# Kimchi white fermentation covering

Tags: yeast, fermentation, mold, sauerkraut, kimchi

It looks like I've developed some nonharmful "kham yeast" on my kimchi ferment.  I've looked online and I'm confident this is not dangerous, but I'm not sure if it is a good sign either.   The kimchi smells great. I tried scraping it off and could only remove 80%.  Any suggestions on next steps needed if any?

[image: white kham yeast]

[image: kham yeast... too much air space?]

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have any weights keeping the vegetables below the surface of the liquid. The easiest one is a sealed plastic bag of brine, or there are various ceramic or glass versions.

Given that Kahm yeast is harmless, rather than opening your airlock (which it appears your jar does have, looking at the top lip) you could have just let it be until the ferment was complete. It tends to be more of a solid mat and easily removed that way, in my limited experience (I've only had Kahm once so far).